# Post only checked values <input type='checkbox' name='Product.Categories[i].Id' value='x' /> to viewmodel

Tags: c#, arrays, checkbox, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I have some trouble getting the checked values in my form model to be posted correctly.

I have this `Product` class

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public int InStock { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice => Price - Discount;
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }//Contains only the categories the product is bound to
}
```

And this `Category` class

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And this `EditVM` class

```
public class EditVM
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories {get; set;}//Contains all the categories in the db
}
```

In my `ProductController` I have the `Edit` action method.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
{
    var product = await _productRepo.Get(id);
    if (product == null) return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    var categories = await _categoryRepo.Get();
    var editVM = new EditVM()
    {
        Product = product,
        Categories = categories
    };
    return View(editVM);
}
```

This is the HTML in my view where I loop through the categories

```
@{var categoryIdList = @Model.Product.Categories.Select(x => x.Id); //Again, contains only the categories the Product is bound to (And gets the id's)
int counter = 0;}
@foreach (Category category in Model.Categories)//Loop through all the categories in the db
{
    if (categoryIdList.Contains(category.Id))
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="Product.Categories[@counter].Id" value="@category.Id" checked />
    }
    else
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="Product.Categories[@counter].Id" value="@category.Id" />
    }
    <label>@category.Name</label>
    { counter++;}
}
```

So far, so good, everything works till here. If I have 5 categories in the db and the product is bound to 2 of them, 5 checkboxes are shown and 2 are checked. So this is perfect.

However, the problem is when I select or deselect checkboxes. Now every `Categories.Id` in the db (Checked or unchecked) is posted to the `HttpPost` `Edit` action method and I want only the Ids posted whom are selected.

```
[HttpPost]
//Note the Product class contains an IEnumerable<Category> Categories prop for the categories the propduct is bound to. This is where the chechbox values must come in play...
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Product Product)
{
    var EditedProduct = await _productRepo.Update(Product);
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

I could chose to make an `EditPostVM` but this has nót my preference. (But it is not forbidden if that's a solution to my problem!). Also changing the incoming viewmodel is ok.

Some extra debug info: So I have 5 categories, so 5 checkboxes. If I select the last three and use the emmidiate window and run the following commands I get these results:

```
this.Request.Form.ElementAt(5)
{[Product.InStock, {120}]}
    Key: "Product.InStock"
    Value: {120}
this.Request.Form.ElementAt(6)
{[Product.SupplierName, {Kipleverancier}]}
    Key: "Product.SupplierName"
    Value: {Kipleverancier}
//Values above are from other form elements. And this works just fine. The problem is below...
this.Request.Form.ElementAt(7)
{[Product.Categories[2].Id, {3}]}
    Key: "Product.Categories[2].Id"
    Value: {3}
this.Request.Form.ElementAt(8)
{[Product.Categories[3].Id, {4}]}
    Key: "Product.Categories[3].Id"
    Value: {4}
this.Request.Form.ElementAt(9)
{[Product.Categories[4].Id, {5}]}
    Key: "Product.Categories[4].Id"
    Value: {5}
```

How can I bind these last three items to my `Product.Categories` prop?

If I check the first 2 items and also the last(out of 5 checkboxes) the first 2 checked items values are bound to `Product.Categories`. The last checked item value is posted, but not bound...

Basically I have 5 categories, so 5 checkboxes. If I select checkbox 2 and 4 I want an array of 2 items to be posted with the id's of the values of checkbox 2 and 4. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a hidden input in your foreach loop, it will send all the categories to the post edit. Just remove it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Product.Categories[@counter].Id" value="@category.Id" />
```

**Update:**

You can use jquery to change the selected checkboxes name when submit the form:

```
@model EditVM
@{
    var categoryIdList = @Model.Product.Categories.Select(x => x.Id); //Again, contains only the categories the Product is bound to (And gets the id's)
    int counter = 0;
}
<form asp-action="Edit" method="post">

    @foreach (Category category in Model.Categories)//Loop through all the categories in the db
    {
        if (categoryIdList.Contains(category.Id))
        {
            <input type="checkbox" name="Product.Categories[@counter].Id" value="@category.Id" checked />
        }
        else
        {
            <input type="checkbox" name="Product.Categories[@counter].Id" value="@category.Id" />
        }
        <label>@category.Name</label>
        { counter++; }
    }
    <input id="btn" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>


@section scripts{ 
<script>
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function () {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('checked','checked')
        }
    })

    $("#btn").on("click", function () {
    var x = 0;
    $("input[type = checkbox]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $(this).attr('name', "Product.Categories[" + x + "].Id")
            x++;
        }
    })
})
</script>
}
```

Comment: I have removed the hidden input. Checked values are posted but not bound. I updated my question. If I check the first 2 items the values are bound to my `Product.Categories` prop. Product.Categories[0].Id and Product.Categories[1].Id are populated so its works. However, if I skip the fist two values, and check the last 3, the values áre posted but nót bound. It tries to bound Product.Categories[2].Id, Product.Categories[3].Id and Product.Categories[4].Id. this is not working because Product.Categories[0].Id and Product.Categories[1].Id are not present. How can I make this work?